# VBA - trigger macro when radio button is selected

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble running a macro automatically when I select a radio button option. There are two radio-button options, which are linked to the cell named "SimType" on the sheet codenamed "MAIN". I have adapted the following code from MSDN and have included it in the module for the MAIN worksheet but cannot get it to function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("SimType")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       RefreshSimsList 
    End If
End Sub
```

I understand Target refers to the ActiveCell so when I manually enter values of 1 or 2 into Range("SimType"), the macro triggers. However, when the cell is altered by the linked radio-buttons, no action is triggered. What can I do to have the sheet recognize that the value has been changed without it being the ActiveCell?

Comment: Unfortunally you will not be enable to do this using a form control. To capturing a radiobutton click event you should use an ActiveX control (RadioButton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in a module

```
Sub OptCommon()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

And simply right click on both the option button and assign macro to it. Now not only the cell value will change but the macro will also run.